# Can not set readonly on input field in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a simple input field:

```
<input id="myInput" class="someClass"></input>
```

and some JQuery code:

```
$(e.currentTarget).prop('readonly', true);
```

where `e.currentTarget`is that `[object HTMLInputElement]` as IE11 names it.

I'm only trying to set this input field to be readonly. In chrome that code works but in IE not.
I tried already:

```
.prop('readonly','readonly');
.prop('readonly', '');
.attr('readonly', true);
```

but none of them works in IE11 ( in chrome everyone of them works)

Comment: have you tried .attr('readOnly', true); ??

Comment: @jrenk: If `prop` doesn't work, `attr` won't.

Comment: It works fine. The input becomes readonly in IE. (I used `$('input')` as a selector).

Comment: @MrUpsidown: The difference appears to be whether the field in question has focus.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't get that. You mean that with IE the field still can be focused?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, this is *bizarre*: If you make the field read-only *while* it has focus, IE11 seems to go a bit bonkers, and one of the ways it goes bonkers is to let you keep modifying the field while the cursor is there — with *some* keystrokes, but not others. Here's an example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7os6yxer/1/)

```
$("#myInput").one("click", function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).prop('readonly', true);
    display("e.currentTarget.readOnly: " + e.currentTarget.readOnly);
});
$("#myInput").on("keydown", function(e) {
    display("e.currentTarget.readOnly: " + e.currentTarget.readOnly);
});
function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Adding this line *before* setting `readOnly` fixes it ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7os6yxer/2/)):

```
$(e.currentTarget).blur();
```

---

Side note: You don't need jQuery to set the `readOnly` property, just:

```
e.currentTarget.readOnly = true; // Note the capital O
```

Comment: thanks. But know it throws me critical angular error in chrome ;) But this is topic for another question.

Answer (score 1):

'Read-only' input element doesn't work consistently in IE 8,9, 10 or 11.

In this case, we can use **onkeydown="javascript: return false;"** in the input element.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Focusin() function in jquery side with Id. When I click on textbox then we remove readony attribute as below:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtCustomerSearch" readonly class="customer-search" 
   placeholder="Search customer:" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off">
```

Jquery:

```
$("#txtCustomerSearch").focusin(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('readonly');
```

});

**Note:** it will working in IE11 and other browser.